# AirTable Formula

Tags: if-statement, concatenation, formula, airtable

I am working on an AirTable. 
Essentially I am concatenating a series of cells with the end goal of generating a filename with the text in those cells.
However, not all file names have the same attributes.

So if you notice in the formula bellow, if the file doesn't have a "DynamicSubitle"
it will leave a double underscore. How could I avoid that?

Here is my formula:

```
CONCATENATE(Airline, "_", Trim, "_", Ratio, "_", Episode, {Language 1}, {Language 2}, {Language 3}, {Language 4}, {Language 5}, "_", {Dynamic Subtitle 1}, "_", Version, "_", {Mpeg Type}, "", Extension)
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be possible, but you have to write a complex if-else formula for this. Pseudocode, will be like first check for empty value if there is empty value don't concatenate else concatenate value with underscore. Formula will be like,

```
CONCATENATE(
   IF(Airline = "","",CONCATENATE(Airline,"_")),
   IF(Trim = "","",CONCATENATE(Trim,"_")),
   IF(Ratio = "","",CONCATENATE(Ratio,"_")),
   ...all other values...,

   IF({Dynamic Subtitle 1} = "","",CONCATENATE({Dynamic Subtitle 1},"_")),

   ...all other values...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can significantly improve readability by concatenating strings with the `&` operator and reversing your logic.

This statement:

```
IF( Airline, Airline & "_")
```

Is identical to writing:

```
IF(Airline = "","",CONCATENATE(Airline,"_"))
```

A single REGEX_REPLACE could also work.